# How to prevent my login sessions to continue in opera browser when I login in chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, opera, session-storage

I've created a php mysql login system for my website. Everything works fine but the problem I face is with my session parsing into different browser then in which I've created/logged in. 
Being specific, I mean that when I log into chrome browser which then creates a session but it also continue in the opera browser, as it also access my session and makes me logged in with the user same as chrome.

I checked logging into fb, stackoverflow and many other websites to see whether the same thing happens with them or not and their session continue to Opera when logging in from Chrome but that didn't happen. But in my website case, it do happen as when I log into chrome, I can access my user from opera too.

How to prevent this from happening as I don't want to share my session like other sites to any other browser..  If they can do, how can I too?
How can I differentiate my session with browser like other website do?

Sort of code I used to create session is written below.

Note: This is not the complete code, I do use hash of a password and take other security measures. This is just an overview how I create a session.

```php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['email']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        echo "You are logged in.";
        header("Location: index.php?log=success");
        unset($_POST);
    } else {
        echo " Something went wrong ";
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to show *how* you're creating sessions, because the behavior you're describing is definitely not the default. I suspect you're doing something like setting a fixed or semi-fixed/predictable session ID, which is a big no-no for this and other security reasons.

Comment: Check the code now

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest for you is to create a `Logs` table or any name of a table where you'll insert a data into it once a user logs in

For example

```
INSERT INTO Logs VALUES (user_id, is_logged_in, timestamps) // the "is_logged_in" here could be a BOOLEAN
```

Now to prevent other people from logging in to different platforms using the same account you have a condition or to check in your login module to fetch the **LATEST RECORD** the user has in the `Logs` table

Sample code snippet:

```
SELECT * FROM Logs WHERE user_id = (Session of the logged in user) ORDER BY timestamps (you may use "created_at" if you have) DESC LIMIT 1
```

The code above fetches the last record of the logged in user in your `Logs` table, now test if the `is_logged_in` is in true flag, then redirect the user back to the log in page, or prevent him/her to continue using the account

Comment: Will try this and let you know.

Comment: one more thing, if the account `LOGS OUT`, don't forget to update the record, or insert another record in the `Logs` table with the value of the **is_logged_in** column to `FALSE` or `ZERO` :)

Comment: @JueViole17 How will you do that if the user just closes the browser window?

Comment: hello sir @ceejayoz, since it's a web technology, we may use javascript or ajax codes. Specifically, we can trigger the "beforeunload" event then hit a query to update or insert a new record inside the `Logs` table

Comment: the "beforeunload" event captures the moment a user closes a browser window

Comment: @JueViole17 You'll find that won't work in a lot of scenarios.